# Что сделать, чтобы сайт не замечал webdriver с использованием прокси Python Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Работаю с селениумом на питоне и хочу сделать возможность переключения прокси (чтобы если переменная `proxy_enable` была `True`, то драйвер запускался с прокси, если `False`, то без).
В данный момент делаю так, чтобы сайты не знали, что я использую вебдрайвер (для этого перехожу по ссылке - там показывает). Если `proxy_enable = False`, то всё работает корректно (сайт показывает, что вебдрайвер не используется), но если `proxy_enable = True`, то сайт уже вебдрайвер замечает.
Что сделать, чтобы сайт не замечал webdriver с использованием прокси? Или как передать опции в драйвер `seleniumwire`?

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from seleniumwire import webdriver as wdw
from time import sleep
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

url = 'https://intoli.com/blog/not-possible-to-block-chrome-headless/chrome-headless-test.html'
proxy_enable = True
full_proxy = 'login:password@ip:port'

options = wd.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={UserAgent().random}')
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')


if proxy_enable:
    proxy_options = {
        'proxy': {
            'https': f'http://{full_proxy}'
        }
    }
    driver = wdw.Chrome(
        'C:\\Users\\aesok\\Desktop\\airdroper\\chromedriver.exe',
        seleniumwire_options=proxy_options
    )
else:
    driver = wd.Chrome(
        'C:\\Users\\aesok\\Desktop\\airdroper\\chromedriver.exe',
        options=options
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: Вы хотите опции передать в драйвер `seleniumwire`?

Comment: Да, если это возможно